# No se puede crear una pregunta con sólo la etiqueta [support]

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Al tratar de crear, editar, o editar las etiquetas de una pregunta con la etiqueta [support](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) sale el siguiente error:

```
Se requiere, al menos, una de estas etiquetas: "bug caracteristica-nueva support".
```

[image: Se requiere, al menos, una de estas etiquetas: "bug caracteristica-nueva support".]

[image: Se requiere, al menos, una de estas etiquetas: "bug caracteristica-nueva support".]

[image: Se requiere, al menos, una de estas etiquetas: "bug caracteristica-nueva support".]

Lo cual no tiene sentido ya que [support](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) es supuestamente una de las etiquetas obligatorias.

Comment: Permitidme investigar un poco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Esto se ha corregido! Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: Listo, ya pude editar la otra pregunta con la etiqueta [tag:soporte]